# Why isn't clearInterval working in this code?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

There is a function which sets an interval using `setInterval()`, but even after calling `clearInterval()`, I can see in the console that the `else` condition is still running. How can I clear that interval properly?

```
function increase(old, step, neu) {
    var i = 0;
    var delay2;

    function countUp() {
        if (i < 5) {
            old += step;
            // console.log("increase")
            $("#total-price-value").text(old + " dollors");
            $("#total-price-value").digits();
            i++;
            delay2 = setInterval(countUp, 80);
        } else {
            clearInterval(delay2);
            console.log(delay2);
        }

    }
    countUp();

}​
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're a little confused about the difference between timeouts and intervals. Timeouts fire only once; intervals fire many times. If you're using an interval, you probably only want to set it once (you're setting it every time). If you're using a timeout, you probably want to set it every time (like you're doing).

In order to fix the problem, you'll either want to switch to timeouts (probably the easiest; just a search/replace) or only set the interval once.

For example, here is how one might use `setTimeout` to count up to five:

```
var count = 0;
function timeoutFired() {
    count++;
    if(count < 5) {
        setTimeout(timeoutFired, 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(timeoutFired, 1000);
```

Using timeouts, we don't need to clear to stop it from counting; simply not setting a timeout will prevent it from running again.

Here is how one might use `setInterval`:

```
var count = 0;
function intervalFired() {
    count++;
    if(count >= 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
var interval = setInterval(intervalFired, 1000);
```

If you want some code running periodically using intervals to stop, you must call `clearInterval`. Note that we only call `setInterval` once, versus `setTimeout` every time we didn't want it to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have mistaken `setInterval` for `setTimeout`. `setInterval` runs the enclosed function *every* `n` milliseconds while `setTimeout` executes only once after `n` milliseconds.

I suppose you wanted to "tick until 5" so [here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9CnfW/1/):

```
function increase(old, step, neu) {
    var i = 0;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (i < 5) {

            //do something at this "tick"
            console.log(i);

            i++;
        } else {
            //else, stop
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },80);

}

increase();
```