# How can I run jQuery load() request each n seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  reload(); 
}); 

function reload() {
  $('div#info').load('http://somesite.ru/script.php');
  setInterval(reload(), 10000);   
}
```

but seems like method reload() runs too fast. Firefox shows me message, about jquery.min.js is sems to busy. How can I make part of page refresh one time for each 10 seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425107/why-isnt-clearinterval-working-in-this-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `()`, also put the `setInterval` function outside the context of the `reload` function.

```
function reload() {
   $('#info').load('http://somesite.ru/script.php');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(reload, 10000);   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
setInterval(reload(), 10000);
```

with:

```
setInterval(reload, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout() instead it is safe and performance wise good than the setInterval() to fulfill your requirement.

```
var time= setTimeout(reload,1000);
```

after checking certain conditions in the reload() method call the setTimeout inside it again

```
function reload()
{
 /// your logic
setTimeout(reload,1000);
}
```

use the above variable to destroy the interval whenever you don't want to reload anymore

```
clearTimout(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval

     setInterval(function(){reload();},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is just use

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() { 
    $('div#info').load('http://somesite.ru/script.php'); 
  }, 10000);
});
```

All works fine. Thanks a lot for your answers.